# Paste Value Based on Formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2010, paste, vba

I'm wondering if it's possible to use VBA to copy the text of a cell instead of the value of a cell.

For example, if cell A1 contains the value `10000`, but is formatted in thousands as `$10.0`, is it possible to set cell B1 equal to the text string `$10.0` from A1? I've tried every variation of standard copy/paste without success.

Note: I would like to allow flexibility for various custom formats, e.g. $, %, thousands, millions, etc. I'm running Excel 2010.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "text". Do you simply want to paste the same value & number format? If so, @Jeanno answer below. If you want to put only the way the value *appears*, then that will be trickier and can't be done by *Paste*, but it can be done. What is the format code for this data?

Comment: Good clarification -- I literally want a text string which mimics the formatting in the cell with the real value. This is because I'm then using the text for data labels in a graph, and the VBA code to do so reads the value of a given cell, not its formatting. Unfortunately, the format code is variable. It can be single units/thousands/millions, $/%/no unit, etc... For that reason I'm not sure I can use pnuts code below.

Comment: Try in vba: `[A2].Value = "'" & [A1].Text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy only the *text* which appears in the cell, you will not use the `Copy` or `Paste` or `PasteSpecial` methods at all.

Instead, you can simply assign one cell's value based on another cell's text:

```
[A2].Value = "'" & [A1].Text
```

I add the single quote to force Excel to treat the value as a string, otherwise it may misinterpret number formats in "General" formatted cells.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```
Range("A1").Copy
Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Comment: Thank you -- perhaps I'm doing this wrong, but the value itself is unchanged (e.g. 10000 vs. $10.0). When I try to use that value as a data label with VBA, the graph displays 10000 instead of the desired "$10.0".

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved with a formula:

```
="$"&TEXT(A1/1000,"00.0")
```

then select, Copy, Paste Special, Values.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the exact formatting is variable. Thousands/millions, $/%, etc... so I need code that's a little more flexible.